# Get all labels name of message using JavaMail MessageIDTerm

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I am using JavaMail API for reading mails from Gmail through IMAP. Now I want to use [MessageIDTerm](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/search/MessageIDTerm.html). I have the message ID but how do I search for folders and get the label names as string? Currently I am getting `Lcom.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage;@2651177` when I use `MessageIDTerm`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the Gmail labels associated with a message, you need to use Gmail extensions to the IMAP protocol.  The standard JavaMail API doesn't support this, but I've created an experimental Gmail provider that adds this support.  This will be in JavaMail 1.4.6.  You can find the 1.4.6 release candidate [here](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/forums/forum/topics/532669-JavaMail-1-4-6-Release-Candidate-is-available).  A description of how to use the new Gmail provider is [here](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/lists/users/archive/2012-08/message/0).

Comment: Is the usage still relevant in the way provided in your link? Or is it included in 1.4.6 or 1.4.7 now without the necessity of using the gimap.jar? Is it still considered an EXPERIMENTAL feature in 1.4.7?

Comment: It's still in the [current release, 1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).  It's still a Gmail-specific feature so you still need the gimap.jar file.  It's experimental mostly in the sense that it might change in incompatible ways from release to release, e.g., because Gmail changes, or because experience shows us a better way to handle these Gmail features.  The current documentation is [here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html).